# POST передача больших данных

Tags: php, post

Есть большой массив данных, как лучше передать их через POST:

1. Одной строкой через запятую, которою преобразовать в массив на бекенде.
2. Массивом element[0]: 123, element[1]: 124 ...

Данных может быть много (порядка 500000)

Comment: В принципе как удобнее. но второй вариант слишком много излишней информации несет. Чаще всего используют json, он все таки компактнее будет и на клиенте в него просто завернуть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый популярный способ будет Json-массив. т.е.
`{ "index" : "value", "index2" : "value",... }`

Массив - не плохой вариант, со своими минусами. Например, тяжесть обработки. Особенно, если данные не строго типизированы. Тогда на беке появится проблема с обработкой массива, если вдруг вместо 1 прилетело "1". Если данные однотипные - используйте тот же json с полем массива. Да и обработать потом данные проще.
Относительно запятой... Зависит от того, что за данные. Надо понимать риски использования сепараторов для таких задач. Если у вас гарантированно не будет запятых - можно и его попытаться.

Какой бы вы не выбрали способ, могу порекомендовать лишь отправлять только строкой данные, а на беке их уже парсить. Или же сделать проверку типов с обеих сторон(до отправки и на беке сразу после принятия их проверить)